# Python: Name search application that requires the use of lists/tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to revise an application that I built for my Python class. The directions are as follows: "Write a program that read the contents of the two files into two separate lists. The user should be able to enter a boy's name, a girl's name, or both, and the application will display messages indicating whether the names were among the most popular." The two files were given to me and their layouts are the issue I am encountering (ex. "1. Jackie", "2. Lisa", etc.). I have created the program to search through both files and find the name that matches the user's input, if it is there. However, because of the layout of the files the only way to pull the names is to search using "1. Jackie", which is wrong. I believe I need to open the files and create lists from each and then covert each list into a 2D list to eliminate the numbers and leave only the names, and save these 2D lists to new files and do the search from the new files. I also know that I have to be able to compensate for the original files to change, and the program will not know how many items are in the file initially until it checks for it. My textbook is not giving me the information I need to do this and I cannot find the answer on Google/Bing. Maybe I am not using the correct keywords, but I am hoping to find help here.
Here is my program code thus far:

## Define main() function

def main():

```
    # Create a bool variable to use as a flag. 
    foundGirl = False

    # Get the search value from the user.
    findGirl = input("What is the girl's name? ")

    # Open the GirlNames.txt file.
    girl_Names = open('GirlNames.txt', 'r')

    # Read the first item in the list.
    searchgirls = girl_Names.readline()

    # Read the rest of the file.
    while searchgirls != '':

            # Strip the \n from the names
            searchgirls = searchgirls.rstrip('\n')

            # Determine whether this item matches the search value.
            if searchgirls == findGirl:
                print(findGirl, 'is found in the top 200 baby names.')
                print()

                # Set the foundGirl flag to True.
                foundGirl = True

            # Read the next value in the file.
            searchgirls = girl_Names.readline()

    # Create a bool variable to use as a flag.          
    foundBoy = False

    # Get the search value from the user.
    findBoy = input("What is the boy's name? ")

    # Open the BoyNames.txt file.
    boy_Names = open('BoyNames.txt', 'r')

    # Read the first item in the list.
    searchboys = boy_Names.readline()

    # Read the rest of the file.
    while searchboys != '':

            # Strip the \n from the names
            searchboys = searchboys.rstrip('\n')

            # Determine whether this item matches the search value.
            if searchboys == findBoy:
                print(findBoy, 'is found in the top 200 baby names.')
                print()

                # Set the foundBoy flag to True.
                foundBoy = True

            # Read the next value in the file.
            searchboys = boy_Names.readline()

    # Close both files.       
    girl_Names.close()    
    boy_Names.close()

    # If the search value was not found in the file
    # display a message.
    if not foundGirl:
       print('That name was not in the list.')

    # If the search value was not found in the file
    # display a message.  
    if not foundBoy:
        print('That name was not in the list.')
```

## Call main() function

main()

And this is a partial copy of the girl's name file to give you a better idea of what I mean by the format:

1. Sophia
2. Emma
3. Olivia
4. Ava
5. Isabella
6. Mia
7. Zoe
8. Lily
9. Emily
10. Madelyn
11. Madison
12. Chloe
13. Charlotte
14. Aubrey
15. Avery
16. Abigail
17. Kaylee
18. Layla
19. Harper
20. Ella
21. Amelia
22. Arianna
23. Riley
24. Aria
25. Hailey

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple structuring problem. You could use Pandas to construct the appropriate data frame but that would be overdoing it. A simple solution is splitting the string on a space and then using its latter half (effectively combining find and substring into one operation).

```
"1. Jackie".split(" ")[1]
```